# team foundation server 2010 web access reports

Tags: tfs

I know its a noob question, but

I have setup a pilot for TFS2010, I want to demo this for business/project managers in our company. From what I think, TFS server allows you to view reports like 
 - Active items
 - bugs
 - time remaining etc

in a chart or graph form. I have installed SQL server reporting service on TFS as well, how can I view reports, do I need share point for this? Do I need to install something extra to enable reports?

The idea is, business/project people will not have VS installed, so they will use web-access to create tasks, bugs etc. Kindly guide me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the demo, you will need to create a TFS project. In the process of doing this you will have to select a so-called process template. For example, the default **MSF Agile template** contains some default reports that will be uploaded to the report server for you while the TFS project is created. No additional actions are needed.

You do not need SharePoint for the reports to be displayed, since the report server has its own website. However, the integrated SharePoint portal shows other project management capabilities, like the sprint backlog, which allows capacity planning for your teams. We use that one and shows-off very good :-)

So, I would say, create the TFS project, with the SharePoint and the Agile template, insert some realistic demo data for user stories, tasks, bugs and register some time on the tasks performed and remaining. If you do this over a couple of days, your report will show-off good, like a sprint is in action.